# Mongoose websocket won't run

Tags: sockets, websocket, webserver, mongoose-web-server

I'm following Mongoose webserver on Github (https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose) and I want to test the websocket sample code.

Here are the codes that I copied:

[image]

Unfortunately when I run the code, it returns the following errors:

```
websocket.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _find_embedded_file
C:\ProjectFolder\WebsocketDemo.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

The [makefile](https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose/blob/master/examples/Makefile) of the examples explain what is missing

There is a rule that generate websocket_html.c that embeded the websocket.html inside a c file (it defines the missing find_embedded_file function).

```
websocket_html.c: websocket.html 
     perl mkdata.pl $< > $@
```

If you prefer to give access to the websocket.html file, this could be done modifying the websocket.c sample

1. Setting the document_root option

   ```
    mg_set_option(server, "document_root", ".");
   ```
2. Not handle the html url in the user handler

   ```
    static int send_reply(struct mg_connection *conn) {
        if (conn->is_websocket) {
        ...
        } else {
            return MG_FALSE; // mongoose will open file specified by the url
        }
    }
   ```